# Swift clearing the contents of an audio file

Tags: swift, audio, avfoundation

I'm trying to clear the content of an audio file without deleting and creating a new file, and I'm totally stumped.

If it's needed here's the code I used to record the audio:

```
func record(){
    let audioSession:AVAudioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
    let audioHeardUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "recordedAudio", ofType: "caf")!)
    let recordSettings: [String: Any] = [AVFormatIDKey:kAudioFormatAppleIMA4,
                                         AVSampleRateKey:44100.0,
                                         AVNumberOfChannelsKey:2,AVEncoderBitRateKey:12800,
                                         AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey:16,
                                         AVEncoderAudioQualityKey:AVAudioQuality.max.rawValue]

    do {
        try audioSession.setCategory("AVAudioSessionCategoryRecord")
    } catch { print("Setting Audio Session Category Error") }

    do {
        try audioSession.setActive(true)
    } catch { print("Activating Audio Session Error") }

    do {
        try recordedAudio = AKAudioFile(forWriting: audioHeardUrl, settings: recordSettings)
    } catch { print("Audio Storing Error") }

    do {
        try audioRecorder = AKNodeRecorder(node: mic, file: recordedAudio)
    } catch { print("Creating Audio Recorder Error") }

    var error: NSError?

    if let e = error {
        print(e.localizedDescription)
    } else {
        do {
            try audioRecorder.record()
        } catch { print("Recording Error") }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's `AKAudioFile`?

Comment: @RhythmicFistman it's a class from an external library called audiokit. It's a subclass of avaudiofile and in this context you can look at it like that